# How to set the standard Iconified location for a JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, location

I've got a class extending JDesktopPane in which I have a JInternalFrame, which I can Iconify, I really like this, but when I iconify it, it goes to the left, bottom side of my screen. I'd like to change this to the right, top side of the screen. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to set that location?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the [DefaultDesktopManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultDesktopManager.html) to manage your `JDesktopPane`.

The `DefaultDesktopManager` class implements the [DesktopManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DesktopManager.html) interface.

Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/DefaultDesktopManager.java#DefaultDesktopManager.getBoundsForIconOf%28javax.swing.JInternalFrame%29) for `DefaultDesktopManager`, the `getBoundsForIconOf` method is protected.  You might be able to extend `DefaultDesktopManager` to get the icon behavior that you want.  Otherwise, you'll have to write your own implementation of the `DesktopManager` interface.