# how to keep minimized jinternalframe on top

Tags: java, swing, layout, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

i have four internal frames and 3 buttons in it .When i hit the maximize button,maximizes but it overlaps all the frames.But my point is that it should show the minimized frames.
please find the code below

```
  package Project;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

public class Test {

    public Test() throws HeadlessException, PropertyVetoException {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Test();
                } catch (HeadlessException ex) {
                    //Logger.getLogger(MinPanel1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                    // Logger.getLogger(MinPanel1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() throws HeadlessException, PropertyVetoException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        final JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 400);
            }
        };

        frame.setContentPane(jdp);
        frame.pack();

        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 0, 0);
        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 200, 0);
        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 400, 0);
        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 600, 0);


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createAndAddInternalFrame(final JDesktopPane jdp, int x, int y) throws PropertyVetoException {
        final JInternalFrame jInternalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Test1", true, true, true, true);
        jInternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);
               final JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1 = new JInternalFrame("Test2", true, true, true, true);
JPanel jp= new JPanel();
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("min");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("[]");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("X");

        jInternalFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2,2,2));
        jInternalFrame1.add(jb1);
        jInternalFrame.setSize(200, 200);//testing
        jInternalFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        JButton jb= new JButton("min");
       // jInternalFrame.add(jb);
      //  jInternalFrame.add(jb3);
        //jInternalFrame.add(jb2);
        jp.add(jb);
        jp.add(jb2);
        jp.add(jb3);

        jInternalFrame.add(jp);
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        try {
                            jInternalFrame.setIcon(true);
                        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                        }

            }


        });
        jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        try {
                            jInternalFrame.setIcon(true);
                        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                        }

            }


        });
        jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {
              jInternalFrame.setMaximum(true);

            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

    }


});jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {
            jInternalFrame.dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

}


});

        BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane = (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) jInternalFrame.getUI()).getNorthPane();
        jInternalFrame.remove(titlePane);


        jInternalFrame.setVisible(true);
        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        jdp.add(jInternalFrame);
                //jdp.add(jInternalFrame1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions and use white space more carefully.

Comment: @trashgod is this your answer?

Comment: Once I fixed the NPE, it works as expected.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754724/how-to-set-the-standard-iconified-location-for-a-jinternalframe)

Comment: @trashgod what is NPE?

Comment: NPE == null pointer exception

Comment: @trashgod why it was required,i have posted the running code,it was not giving any single error

Comment: From what I can see its the default behavior and doesnt seem to be over com-able by `JDesktopPane#setComponentZOrder(Component com, int i)` when the `JInternalFrame` is *iconified*. it works fine when its in normal state.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/); the NPE was from `remove(titlePane)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try: `JDesktopPane#setComponentZOrder(Component com, int i)`. 
[As per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29):

> Moves the specified component to the specified z-order index in the
>   container. The z-order determines the order that components are
>   painted; the component with the highest z-order paints first and the
>   component with the lowest z-order paints last. Where components
>   overlap, the component with the lower z-order paints over the
>   component with the higher z-order.
>
> ...
>
> Note:
>
> Not all platforms support changing the z-order of
>   heavyweight components from one container into another without the
>   call to removeNotify. There is no way to detect whether a platform
>   supports this, so developers shouldn't make any assumptions.

This will allow you to set the order of the `JInternalFrame`s contained within `JDesktopPane`.

**UPDATE:**

As per my comment:

> From what I can see its the default behavior and doesnt seem to be
>   over com-able by `JDesktopPane#setComponentZOrder(Component com, int i)`
>   when the `JInternalFrame` is *iconified*. it works fine when its in *normal
>   state*

**Solution:**

I suggest adjusting the layer on which maximized `JInternalFrame` is shown:

```
    jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                if (jInternalFrame.isMaximum()) {//restore
                    jInternalFrame.pack();
                } else {//maximize
                    jInternalFrame.setMaximum(true);
                }
                jdp.remove(jInternalFrame);
                jdp.add(jInternalFrame, JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
                jdp.revalidate();
                jdp.repaint();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

We must also not forget to add it back to the `DEFAULT_LAYER` when it is minimized:

```
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                if (jInternalFrame.getLayer() == JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER) {
                    jdp.remove(jInternalFrame);
                    jdp.add(jInternalFrame, JDesktopPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                    jdp.revalidate();
                    jdp.repaint();
                }
                jInternalFrame.pack();
                jInternalFrame.setIcon(true);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            }

        }
    });
```

Here is full code:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

public class Test {

    public Test() throws HeadlessException, PropertyVetoException {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Test();
                } catch (HeadlessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() throws HeadlessException, PropertyVetoException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        final JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(600, 400);
            }
        };

        frame.setContentPane(jdp);
        frame.pack();

        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 0, 0);
        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 300, 0);
        createAndAddInternalFrame(jdp, 0, 200);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createAndAddInternalFrame(final JDesktopPane jdp, int x, int y) throws PropertyVetoException {
        final JInternalFrame jInternalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Test1", true, true, true, true);
        jInternalFrame.setLocation(x, y);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();

        JButton jb = new JButton("min");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("max/restore");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("close");

        jInternalFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        jp.add(jb);
        jp.add(jb2);
        jp.add(jb3);

        jInternalFrame.add(jp);

        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (jInternalFrame.getLayer() == JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER) {
                        jdp.remove(jInternalFrame);
                        jdp.add(jInternalFrame, JDesktopPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
                        jdp.revalidate();
                        jdp.repaint();
                    }
                    jInternalFrame.pack();
                    jInternalFrame.setIcon(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    if (jInternalFrame.isMaximum()) {//restore
                        jInternalFrame.pack();
                    } else {//maximize
                        jInternalFrame.setMaximum(true);
                    }
                    jdp.remove(jInternalFrame);
                    jdp.add(jInternalFrame, JDesktopPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
                    jdp.revalidate();
                    jdp.repaint();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    jInternalFrame.dispose();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        BasicInternalFrameTitlePane titlePane = (BasicInternalFrameTitlePane) ((BasicInternalFrameUI) jInternalFrame.getUI()).getNorthPane();
        jInternalFrame.remove(titlePane);

        jInternalFrame.pack();
        jInternalFrame.setVisible(true);

        jdp.add(jInternalFrame);
    }
}
```

Comment: what would be the value of i ?

Comment: @sukant the index in the container i.e anything less than the maximzed should paint after it

Comment: if I put the index value as zero then only it works .it Gives runtime error for other values.The code runs for zero value but my desired output is not coming.So i asked what would be the value of i

Comment: +1 I couldn't make `setComponentZOrder()` work, but this is an instructive approach.

Comment: @trashgod yeah I could only get it working for frames which werent iconifed. Oh well there must be some limitations when making very portable code I guess :P

Comment: @sukant: As an example, my platform's UI delegate, `InternalFrameUI`, has no `BasicInternalFrameTitlePane`, hence the NPE.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp i have stuck in the middle and do not why only one panel is working.can you please sort it out?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the result of calling `moveToBack()` in the maximize button handler. Also remember to call `pack()` on the internal frame.

Addendum: I've updated the example to include <kbd>max</kbd>, <kbd>min</kbd> and <kbd>icon</kbd> buttons. The buttons use `Action` for easier testing, and the internal frames have distinct names. See [`createToolBar()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513) to change the L&F dynamically, e.g.

```
frame.add(createToolBar(frame), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

//* @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14874924/230513 */
public class Test {

    public Test() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane() {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(600, 400);
            }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            createInternalFrame(jdp, 100 * i, 100 * i);
        }
        frame.add(jdp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createInternalFrame(final JDesktopPane jdp, int x, int y) {
        final JInternalFrame jif = new JInternalFrame("Test" + x, true, true, true, true);
        jif.setLocation(x, y);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("max") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    jif.setMaximum(true);
                    jif.moveToBack();
                } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }));
        jp.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("min") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    jif.setMaximum(false);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }));
        jp.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("icon") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    jif.setIcon(true);
                } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));
        jif.add(jp);
        jif.pack();
        jif.setVisible(true);
        jdp.add(jif);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've re-factored your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) to focus on my understanding of the problem and make experimentation easier.

Comment: @trashgod i have done a code which satisfies my requirement but out of three panels only one panel is working.Can you please rectify where the mistake i have made.If yes then please let me know so that i will post the code here

Comment: @DavidKroukamp how my question was deleted and who did this?

Comment: @sukant: Sorry, DYM = "did you mean". I'm not sure about deleted; except for tags, only you [edited this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14873889/revisions).