# Resize JFrame to JPanels inside JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I'm working on a Swing GUI using the `JLayeredPane`. The `JFrame` has a `JLayeredPane` which contains two `JPanel`s. Later I want to display some components in the `JPanel`s, I cut this part of the code to make it shorter for you.

How do I resize the `JFrame` to the sizes of the `JPanel`s? `frame.pack()` does not work and without the line setting the preferred size the GUI will show with minimal size.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestGUI {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    private JPanel panelBottom;
    private JPanel panelTop;
    private MainMenuBar menuBar;

    public TestGUI() {
        // panel bottom:
        panelBottom = new JPanel();
        panelBottom.setSize(1000, 500);
        panelBottom.setBackground(new Color(0, 100, 0, 100));
        panelBottom.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        // panel top:
        panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelTop.setSize(950, 450);
        panelTop.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 100, 100));
        panelTop.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        // layered pane:
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.add(panelBottom, 1);
        layeredPane.add(panelTop, 0);
        // frame building:
        frame = new JFrame();
        menuBar = new MainMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 600)); // <-- Without this the GUI will be very small
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack(); // <-- does not work!
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGUI();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I could just change the preferred size line to fit the biggest JPanel, but i ask the question because I want the `JFrame` to resize depending on the size of the `JPanel`s dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in [*How to Use Layered Panes: Laying Out Components in a Layered Pane*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html#layout), "Although a layered pane has no layout manager by default, you can still assign a layout manager to the layered pane." Use `OverlayLayout`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513), for overlapping panels.

Alternatively, use [`JInternalFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html), which *does* allow you to `pack()` the internal frames individually, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14874924/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4091329/230513).